# NavigationController.pushViewController in Custom Segue does not work - Swift 2.0 - iOS 9.1

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift2, uistoryboardsegue, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm writing a custom segue in UIStoryboardSegue. I use a CATransition to create a right to left custom animation. If I used `sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false);`, it does not take me to the second view. It just performs the right to left animation and stays on the first view. I have debugged this code, and I found that sourceViewController.navigationController is nil. I have a UINavigationController between the first view and the second view.

I have also tried to replace this line of code with `sourceViewController.presentViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil);`. The transition does happen, but it happens too fast that I can't see the right to left animation.

My complete code in this UIStoryboardSegue is the following:

```
override func perform() {


    let sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController;
    let destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController;
    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()

    transition.duration = 0.25;
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;

    sourceViewController.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")

    sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false);
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sourceViewController.pushViewController` is correct. The reason that I was getting nil for the `sourceViewController.navigationController` was that, I placed the navigation controller between the first view and the second view. The correct way of placing the navigation controller is to place it before the first view.

[image: This is the correct way of placing the navigation controller:]

Comment: This answer might be correct, but is poorly explained. Please complete the answer

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My problem was:

```
sourceViewController.navigationController == nil
```

In SourceViewController's storyboard file, clicked the ViewController, and then:

```
Editor > Embed in > Navigation controller
```

Then Xcode generated three ViewControllers: One initial NavigationController, then SourceViewController and DestinationViewController.

Now the custom segue works.

Let me know if this helped ya :-)